# Why can I use pure function to convert to applicative

Tags: haskell

I have following type definition:

```
  data Hello a b =  Hi a
                  | Sali b
                  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

and it isn't an instance of `Applicative` but I can still use `pure` to convert it to `Applicative` why?

```
*ExercisesTraversable Data.Monoid Control.Applicative> :t pure $ Hi 34
pure $ Hi 34 :: (Num a, Applicative f) => f (Hello a b)

*ExercisesTraversable Data.Monoid Control.Applicative> pure $ Hi 34
Hi 34
```

And when I try:

```
*ExercisesTraversable Data.Monoid Control.Applicative> (Sali (*2)) <*> (Sali 4)

<interactive>:23:1: error:
    * Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Applicative (Hello a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall b a. (Num b, Applicative (Hello a)) => Hello a b
```

that is clear, because it isn't an `Applicative` instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you aren't specifying any `Applicative` type in particular, `ghci` is defaulting to `IO`, i.e. `pure $ Hi 34` returns a value of type `Num a => IO (Hello a b)`. That is, `Hello a b` isn't the `f` in `a -> f a`, it's the `a`.

You can see more explicitly that `Hello a b` is the typed wrapped by an arbitrary `Applicative` by specifying various `Applicative` functors for the value:

```
Prelude> (pure $ Hi 34) :: Either String (Hello Int b)
Right (Hi 34)
Prelude> (pure $ Hi 34) :: Maybe (Hello Int b)
Just (Hi 34)
Prelude> (pure $ Hi 34) :: [Hello Int b]
[Hi 34]
```

Comment: When I look in prelude `Prelude> :t pure $ Hi 34
pure $ Hi 34 :: (Num a, Applicative f) => f (Hello a b)` I can not see the `IO` type. Why?

Comment: `IO` is only used as a default when you try to evaluate it.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `pure x` it is not `x` that should be `Applicative`, but the whole `pure x` expression. Take a look at `pure` type:

```
Prelude> :t pure
pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a
```

See? You pass it `a`, but `Applicative` constraint is on `f`, and that `f` only appears in the result. So, it is the result that should be of class `Applicative`, and as @chepner said, GHCi prompt defaults to `IO`, which is `Applicative`.